# Export higher resolution .avi file

Tags: plotting, manipulate, export, formatting, video

How can I increase the .avi resolution of the video that produces the following code (because now it is blurry):

```
Export["Manipulate.avi", %20]
```

Comment: You may try to adjust the `ImageSize` or `ImageResolution` options of `Export`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher ImageResolution does not increase the resolution. How can I try ImagineSzie?

Comment: For example, `Export["Manipulate.avi", manipulate,ImageSize->{1920,1080}]` should produce HD resolution.

Comment: `ImageSize` is an option for your graphic frames which will be exported to avi. Did you use any compression of the video? Blur can appear as result of wrong settings of video compression.

Comment: @Rom38 Where can I see if it is compressed?

Comment: @Looper You can look an information about encoding in the most of video players. BTW, another way is to set certain bitrate inside `Export` and then look onto the filesize of the output. If your file is much less than `bitrate*duration_in_seconds` then it is compressed.